# the problem is that it returns 0.0.0.0 in some users, and not the user's real ip

Tags: php

I am having problems when registering the ip of the users who see some video of a wordpress
this is my function that gets the ip, the problem is that it returns 0.0.0.0 in some users, and not the user's real ip

```
function get_ip_address()
{
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
if ($ip === '::1') {
    return '127.0.0.1';
}
return $ip;}
```

this is more on the server or code side, someone who can help me?

Comment: Getting the IP address of a user is always a problem. Even if you can get an IP address, there's no guarantee that it's the user's real address. With some broadband systems the user's IP address will change daily. Find another way - maybe set a cookie.

Comment: Yes, all of those vars are set by the client or some system in between and could be anything.  A company using a proxy or firewall NAT would show all thousands of users as the same IP.

Comment: did a "live" request send you `0.0.0.0` or did maybe some (wp) plugins anonymize the ip after a period?

Comment: Your code is fine, the computer making the request is sending 0.0.0.0 as its IP address.

Comment: yes, the computer making the request is sending 0.0.0.0 as its IP address.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid address. If the sending computer is actually sending that then there's no way to send a response. More likely, the server is simply not providing it to PHP.

Comment: Thanks for answering !!, I found the solution to why this happened and it was because the function only accepts ipv4, and those obtained in ipv6 were sent as 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it will return the first non empty string and `0.0.0.0` count as one. You could try adding another rule to your if like so:

```
function get_ip_address()
{
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']!=="0.0.0.0") {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']!=="0.0.0.0") {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
if ($ip === '::1') {
    return '127.0.0.1';
}
return $ip;}
```

The way i do it, is i store all possible variables in an array and itérate the array for something that looks valid. Something like this that will filter empty value and keep the rest:

```
$IPS=array_filter([
   'addr'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
   'forx'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'],
   'http'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'],
]);
```

You could also `str_replace` as the callback of `array_map` it to remove 0.0.0.0 values within the array (if you wish to discard those).

Further more, after filtering bad entry you can use `reset()`on the array to get the 1st value in the remaining item if you can work with only 1 ip. That is, if you setted the array in your prefered order.

Comment: None of this will guarantee a valid, real IP address for the client machine. If the OP is hoping to use this information for any sort of tracking then it's so much wasted effort.

Comment: I assumed OP know IP can be spoofed. Even tho there is no reliable way to get the client IP you have more accurate way than returning the first non empty value found.

Comment: Thanks for answering !!, I found the solution to why this happened and it was because the function only accepts ipv4, and those obtained in ipv6 were sent as 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
}

echo get_client_ip();
```